# Get combobox value inside updatepanel on jquery autocomplete textbox

Tags: jquery, updatepanel, jquery-ui-autocomplete

i have two combo boxes inside ajax update panel and a **JQuery Autocomplete** textbox outside the update panel

my problem is when i select from client combobox i need to pass value to service method

this is my code **`agentid`** is always empty

```
jQuery(function test(agentid) {
            agentid = $("#val_client").val();
            options = { 
                        serviceUrl: '../../proxy/workorder/WorkOrderService.svc/GetAllPropertyListAutoComplete', 
                        params: { _agency: agentid },
                        onSelect: function (value, data) {
                               var record = new Array();
                               record = data.split('|');
                               document.getElementById('workTitle').value = record[0] ? record[0] : record[1];
                               document.getElementById('workAddress').value = record[1] ? record[1] : record[0];
                               document.getElementById('workSiteContact').value = record[2];
                               document.getElementById('workSiteContactNumber').value = record[3];
                               $('#workTitle').attr('readonly', true);
                               $('#workAddress').attr('readonly', true);
                                return false;
                          }
                       }
            a = $('#txt_Properties').autocompletev2(options);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your dropdownlist id "val_client"?

Comment: try to get its selected value using javascript like;
document.getElementById('val_client')[document.getElementById('val_client').selectedIndex].value